# Automatic close evil-make buffer

Tags: spacemacs, latex, evil

I'm using evil mode (Spacemacs to be specific) and working with LaTeX projects. I use `evil-make` or `:make` command to compile the current LaTeX project to PDF file. I find it quite annoying that whenever I run the command, it opens up a new buffer showing the output, and I have to switch to the buffer the close it.

I'm wondering if there is a way to automatically close the `evil-make` command buffer if the make is successful?
If not, can how can I change the `evil-make` command behavior so that when it is called, the emacs can make the output buffer as the currently active buffer (so that I can close it immediately, without switch buffer).